# In page anchors and routes on a single page JS application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, javascript-framework

I have a single page application that I wrote with JS.  There's a function bound to hash change events ( [jquery-hashchange-plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) ) .

On a hash change event I call the matching route's defined controller init method. The problem is that sometime I use the hashes for in-page anchors and I don't want the controller's init method to be called again.

for example the route /#info has the following in-page anchors : /#info/about and /#info/contact.

The only way I can think of solving this issue is by setting the last hash(or route) on every hash change and checking on route change if the route is the same.

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what's actually is your problem. Why would you have to run the init method every time if you don't want to? Since it's a single page application you'll be able to hold your controller (that is inited) in memory so that you don't have to keep initing it?

Comment: The init method setups the new view so the controller object is always memory in memory but the method setups up the page and handles dom events ( similar to a backbone view ). So when going from one page to another I want to have the init method called. One of the things I do before calling the init is scrolling to the top of the page - Which is another thing I don't want on an in-page anchor click.

Comment: Maybe you should keep track on which "state" you application is in when the has-change event is triggered so you know if it's from or outside the same controller or if it's time to switch current controller